# THREE.JS: objects that should not appear as visible appear as visible

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm in the process of tinkering together a solar system simulator and it is all going well with the exception of one part: when a moon or a planet goes behind its parent body, you can still see it!

There are no transparent objects in the scene, and I have not made any modifications to the order in which objects are rendered, so I'm at a loss as to why objects appear when they are behind another object.

I'm using three.js r71 (problem still appears in r84, though).

To see where it goes wrong: check out http:mrhuffman.net/projects/gp and pick the Martian system; you will see how Phobos or Deimos are still visible even though they are behind Mars.

Here's the code for the scene. It's not as tidy as it could be as I just started working on it, so if you need clarifications or have questions, shoot!

```
import THREE from '../vendor/three';
import OrbitControls from '../vendor/OrbitControlsES6';
import ColladaLoader from '../vendor/ColladaLoaderES6';
import nBodyProblem from '../algorithms/nBodyProblem';

const scene = ( function () {

  //Full screen action

  let w = window.innerWidth;
  let h = window.innerHeight;

  let requestAnimationFrameId = null;
  let scene = null;
  let camera = null;
  let controls = null;
  let renderer = null;
  let system = null;
  let dae = null;

  let cameraControlsWrapper = null;
  let orbitButton = null;
  let view3DButton = null;

  let pathCanvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  pathCanvas.style.display = 'none';
  pathCanvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(misc/starfield.jpg)';
  let ctxPath = pathCanvas.getContext( '2d' );

  let massCanvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  massCanvas.style.display = 'none';
  massCanvas.style.position = 'absolute';
  massCanvas.style.zIndex = 2;
  massCanvas.style.top = 0;
  massCanvas.style.bottom = 0;
  let ctxMass = massCanvas.getContext( '2d' );

  pathCanvas.width = w;
  pathCanvas.height = h;

  massCanvas.width = w;
  massCanvas.height = h;

  ctxPath.translate( w / 2, h / 2 );
  ctxMass.translate( w / 2, h / 2 );

  function showOrbits() {
    orbitButton.style.display = 'none';
    cameraControlsWrapper.style.display = 'none';
    pathCanvas.style.display = 'block';
    massCanvas.style.display = 'block';
    view3DButton.style.display = 'block';
  }

  function hideOrbits() {
    view3DButton.style.display = 'none';
    pathCanvas.style.display = 'none';
    massCanvas.style.display = 'none';
    orbitButton.style.display = 'block';
    cameraControlsWrapper.style.display = 'block';
  }

  function createBody( radius, name, type ) {
    let segments = type !== 'asteroid' ? 32 : 6;
    let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, segments, segments );
    let map;
    let bumpMap;

    switch( type ) {
      case 'asteroid':    
        map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/Phobos.jpg');
        bumpMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/PhobosBump.jpg');
        break;

      case 'custom':    
        map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/Acid.jpg');
        break;

      case 'star':    
        map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/Sun.jpg');
        break;

      case 'spacecraft':    
        scene.add( dae );
        return dae;

      default:    
        map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/' + name + '.jpg');
        bumpMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/Phobos.jpg');
    }

    let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: map, bumpMap: bumpMap, bumpScale: 0.02 } );
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.rotation.x = 1.5;
    scene.add( mesh );    
    return mesh;    
}

  function sceneSetup( callback, scenario, container, camPos, camFocus, viewOrbits, view3D, cameraControls ) {
    if ( scenario.model === undefined ) {
      callback( scenario, container, camPos, camFocus, viewOrbits, view3D, cameraControls );     
      return;    
    }

    let loader = new ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load( './models/' + scenario.model + '/' + scenario.model + '.dae', ( collada ) => {    
      dae = collada.scene;
      dae.scale.setScalar( 1 / 800 );

      callback( scenario, container, camPos, camFocus, viewOrbits, view3D, cameraControls );
    });
  }

  function initSimulation( scenario, container, camPos, camFocus, viewOrbits, view3D, cameraControls ) {

    cameraControlsWrapper = cameraControls;
    orbitButton = viewOrbits;
    orbitButton.addEventListener( 'click', showOrbits, false );
    view3DButton = view3D;
    view3DButton.addEventListener( 'click', hideOrbits, false );
    hideOrbits();
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, w / h, 0.000001, 1500 );
    //Prevent rolling of the camera when you view a body from another    
    camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );    
    camera.position.set( 0, 90, 150 );    
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(light);    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(w, h);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

    container.appendChild( pathCanvas );
    container.appendChild( massCanvas );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    //Create a new n-body problem from the selected scenario    
    system = new nBodyProblem( {
      g: scenario.g,
      law: scenario.law,
      dt: scenario.dt,
      masses: scenario.masses
    });

    //Create visual manifestations of the planets, asteroids and star(s)
    for (let i = 0; i < system.masses.length; i++) {
      let mass = system.masses[ i ];
      mass.manifestation = createBody( mass.radius, mass.name, mass.type );
    }

    const render = function () {    
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame( render );    
      //Update state vectors          system.updatePositionVectors().updateVelocityVectors().updateBarycenter().calculateElapsedTime();

      //Check if a rocket should be fired and if so check if it should be fired in this iteration; should that be the case, fire!    
      if ( scenario.rocketBurn === true ) {    
        if ( system.elapsedTime === scenario.rocketBurnTime ) {    
          for ( let i = 0; i < system.masses.length; i++ ) {    
            if ( system.masses[ i ].type === 'spacecraft' ) {    
                system.masses[ i ].vx = scenario.afterRocketBurnVelocity.vx;
                system.masses[ i ].vy = scenario.afterRocketBurnVelocity.vy;
                system.masses[ i ].vz = scenario.afterRocketBurnVelocity.vz;
            }   
          }    
        }    
      }

      ctxMass.clearRect( -0.5 * w, -0.5 * h, w, h );

      //Put all the masses in their new positions and set camera position and focus    
      for (let i = 0; i < system.masses.length; i++) {    
        let mass = system.masses[ i ];    
        let x = mass.x * scenario.scale;
        let y = mass.y * scenario.scale;
        let z = mass.z * scenario.scale;

        mass.manifestation.position.set( x, y, z );    
        let camR = camPos.value;
        let name = mass.name;

        if ( camR === name ) {    
          camera.position.set( x, y, z + ( mass.radius * 1.2 ) );
          controls.enabled = false;    
        } else if ( camR === 'free' ) {    
          controls.enabled = true;    
        }

        if ( camFocus.value === name ) {    
          camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z ) );    
          //If the camera mode is free, the user can pan, orbit and have fun
          if ( camPos === 'free' ) controls.target = new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z );    
        }

        ctxPath.fillStyle = mass.color;
        ctxPath.fillRect( x, y, 1, 1 );

        ctxMass.beginPath();
        ctxMass.fillStyle = mass.color;
        ctxMass.arc( x, y, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI );
        ctxMass.fill();

        ctxMass.font = "14px Arial";
        ctxMass.fillText( mass.name, x + 8, y );    
      }

      //Put the barycenter of the system in its new position

      let barycenterX = system.x * scenario.scale;
      let barycenterY = system.y * scenario.scale;

      ctxMass.strokeStyle = 'limegreen';
      ctxMass.lineWidth = 2;
      ctxMass.beginPath();
      ctxMass.moveTo( barycenterX - 20, barycenterY );
      ctxMass.lineTo( barycenterX + 20, barycenterY );
      ctxMass.moveTo( barycenterX, barycenterY - 20 );
      ctxMass.lineTo( barycenterX, barycenterY + 20 );
      ctxMass.stroke();

      ctxMass.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
      ctxMass.font = "14px Arial";
      ctxMass.fillText( 'Barycenter', barycenterX, barycenterY - 25 );

      renderer.render( scene, camera );

    };

    //Makes the scene responsive
    //Note that traces are cleared when the size of the viewport changes

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    function onWindowResize() {    
      w = window.innerWidth;
      h = window.innerHeight;

      camera.aspect = w / h;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();    
      renderer.setSize( w, h );    

      pathCanvas.width = w;
      pathCanvas.height = h;

      massCanvas.width = w;
      massCanvas.height = h;

      ctxPath.clearRect( -0.5 * w, -0.5 * h, w, h );
      ctxMass.clearRect( -0.5 * w, -0.5 * h, w, h );

      ctxPath.translate( w / 2, h / 2 );
      ctxMass.translate( w / 2, h / 2 );    
    }    
    render();
  }

  //Tidy up    
  function resetSimulation() {    
    orbitButton.removeEventListener( 'click', showOrbits );
    view3DButton.removeEventListener( 'click', hideOrbits );

    cancelAnimationFrame( requestAnimationFrameId );    
    ctxPath.clearRect( -0.5 * w, -0.5 * h, w, h );

    renderer.domElement.parentNode.removeChild( renderer.domElement );
    pathCanvas.parentNode.removeChild( pathCanvas );
    massCanvas.parentNode.removeChild( massCanvas );    
  }

  //API    
  return {
    startSimulation: (  scenario, container, camPos, camFocus, viewOrbits, view3D, cameraControls  ) => {    
        sceneSetup( initSimulation, scenario, container, camPos, camFocus, viewOrbits, view3D, cameraControls );        
    },
    resetSimulation: resetSimulation
  };    
}());

export default scene;
```

Comment: Your `material` is not defined for all types of geometry in `createBody()`

Comment: Yea, that is correct; you don't need to specify a material if you're loading a collada model, right? The collada models appear in the scenarios they are included in, or have I missed something (I'm a THREE noob)? Could you perhaps give me a code sample with reference to the code I provided?

Comment: No I mean from the way your code is you might get a material definition where `map` and `bumpmap` are null and assign that to a mesh.

Comment: A collada model will only be returned by the createBody function if the scenario.model flag is undefined (see the simulationSetup function), i.e has not been specified. And the case, where a collada model is loaded, in the switch statement is only triggered if the mass is of the type "spacecraft", so if there are no masses with the property type set to spacecraft that issue should not arise...?

Comment: P.S. If the mass is a spacecraft, the function is terminated through the return statement that returns the collada model, so for the scenarios that include collada models, the final part of the function should never be evaluated.

Comment: So then it must be the Collada models fault.

Comment: Just cut out the collada code but I the problem persists, so I'll just bang my head into a wall of my choice for a while; thanks for your feedback, though!